# MVC 3 How to get the last browser history entry?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

when an user enters on a View, from the WebBrowser he can goes back to the previous page by clicking the WebBrowser's back button.

Is it possible to get that back URL when entering on that View ?

I want to assign that URl for one of the buttons on that View. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use [UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) of the request:

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

This property returns the value of the [Http referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) value sent with the request, which is not guaranteed to be correct or even there - some browsers and tools enable you to block them.